# At what level are Spell Scrolls used?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

I look for information that I have not found in the PHB or in the DMG. With what level are the spells of a scroll cast?

Example: a level 20 wizard with a scroll of *Magic Missile*. At what level does he cast the spell on the scroll?

In what section or page does the rule that explains it appear?

Comment: Hello! Am I correct in assuming you have a non-English copy of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*?

Comment: I think the intent of the comment asking the above question is that if you are using a non-english copy the page numbers would be different and that would be helpful information.

Comment: Near duplicate of [Can a spell scroll be upcast using a higher-level spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138361).  Answers on that question answer this one.

Answer (score 12):

### Spells cast from magic items are cast at their lowest level

Whenever a magic item allows you to cast a spell, unless it specifically says otherwise, it's cast at its lowest level. This is explained in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, in the chapter **Magic items**, in the sub-section **Activating an Item**:

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item, often by expending charges from it. **The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell and caster level**, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 7):

## You cast the spell at its lowest level.

Scrolls are defined by the spell they contain. If they contain a 1st-level spell (like *Magic Missile*), then they are a *Spell Scroll (level 1)*.

From the DMG (page 141) or [online](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Magic%20Items#toc_8):

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from
> the item. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell
> level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and
> requires no components, unless the item's description
> says otherwise. The spell uses its normal casting time,
> range, and duration, and the user of the item must
> concentrate if the spell requires concentration.

You can also find info on Scrolls on DMG (page 139), or more specifically on DMG (page 200). On-line resources are [here](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spell%20Scroll#content):

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell without providing any material Components. [...] The level of the spell on the scroll determines the spell’s saving throw DC and Attack bonus, as well as the scroll’s rarity, as shown in the Spell Scroll table.