# Is it possible to have a scroll which casts a spell at higher than its spell list level?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

I know that, by default, magic items cast spells of the lowest level possible for that spell.

However, is there any specific way by the rules to have a scroll that casts a spell at a higher level than that spell appears in a spell list? For example, can I ever have a scroll that casts *magic missile* (a 1st level spell) at 2nd level?

Note: I am not asking if you can take a normal 1st level scroll of *magic missile* and cast it at a higher level as in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138361/can-a-spell-scroll-be-upcast-using-a-higher-level-spell-slot). I am asking if 2nd level scrolls of *magic missile* can be made/exist at all - a related but different question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Yes.

If the description says it does, then it can.  Otherwise, the lowest level is assumed.

General rule for [casting spells from magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/magic-items#Spells):

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, **unless the item's description says otherwise.**

### Scroll Levels

[*Spell scrolls*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll) are not explicitly stated to always be at the lowest possible level for the spell.  That is the default for magic items.  So a "scroll of magic missile" would be a level 1 scroll and follow the table for casting an L1 scroll.  However, a "scroll of magic missile level two" would be a level two spell scroll.  It still fits with the general description of spell scrolls, and with magic items since the description states the spell level.

### Scribing

Xanathar's Guide to Everything offers guidance on the cost and nature of scribing spell scrolls.  It has a table relating the level of the spell to the cost of it and the requirements on the scribe.

Following the table, scribing a 2nd level magic missile scroll would take the cost from 25gp to 250gp and doubles the required time to complete the task.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, if specified on the scroll

Following [Sage Advice](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/06/02/spell-scroll-level/) (quoted below) it's possible to come across scrolls with specified levels for the inscribed spell.

> **@newbiedm**
>    would a 5e spell scroll point out at what level the spell is cast, for those spells that can be cast using higher spell slots? #dnd
>
> **@JeremyECrawford**
>    The spell on a spell scroll is at the spell's lowest level, unless a particular scroll says otherwise